# Iterating over second array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have one flat array that I use to generate a tree later on:

```
[0] => array
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
[1] => array
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
[2] => array
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 12
[3] => array
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 7
```

The values in this array are plain id's, I want to convert them into full names. I can get those names from the database, with corresponding id's, so that's my sample output array:

```
[0] => array
    ['id'] => 1
    ['name'] => 'sample name'
[1] => array
    ['id'] => 2
    ['name'] => 'foo'
[2] => array
    ['id'] => 3
    ['name'] => 'bar'
```

So now I have to iterate over the first array, and compare each value to the value from the second array...How can I do that without using foreach loop in every iteration of the external loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Means u want to compare all the element of second array with each iterated value of first array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the 2nd array so you can reference it in the first.

```
$newarr = array();
foreach ($secondval as $val )
{
    $newarr[ $val->id ] = $val->name;
}
```

Then use this in the first loop.